# Loop over a string and add the delimiter back to the substring

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a column with strings. I would like to split the string in each cell by 'Juice', but keep 'juice' if it is not in the last substring.

Example:  df['value'] looks like below:

```
 1. applejuice, orangejuice, juice, applejuice, pineapple juice,  berriesjuice 
 2. carrotjuice, juice, pinapple juice, water, berriesjuice, juice
```

my output of the new colmn df['value2'] would look like this:

```
1. [applejuice, orangejuice, juice], [applejuice, pineapple ,juice], [berriesjuice]
2. [carrotjuice, juice], [pinapple juice], [water, berriesjuice, juice]
```

Comment: Why did `pineapple juice` disappear in 2. ?

Comment: Thanks. I just modified the question. Typed two 'juice' in the first row by accident.

Comment: The outputs are not quite clear: in 1. "pineapple juice" gets split, but in 2. it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying this function to the `value` column should do the job. It starts by splitting on ', ' (note the space), and then makes new sublists every time it encounters 'juice' on its own.

```py
def separate(string):
    substrings = [[]]
    for x in string.split(', '):
        substrings[-1].append(x)
        if x == 'juice':
            substrings.append([])
    return substrings

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value' : [
    'applejuice, orangejuice, juice, applejuice, pineapple juice, juice, berriesjuice', 
    'carrotjuice, juice, pinapple juice, water, berriesjuice, juice'
    ]})
df['value2'] = df.value.apply(separate, axis=0)
```

I'm not sure about speed though.

Comment: Sorry I missed your response.  Thank you for the code. I actually used yours as well. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answers you used :)

Answer (score 1):

Unclear why you need a dataframe, but start by splitting on commas, then iterate and check when the strings are equal to `juice` or not.

```
import re

lines = [
  'applejuice, orangejuice, juice, applejuice, pineapple juice, juice, berriesjuice',
  'carrotjuice, juice, pinapple juice, water, berriesjuice, juice'
]

def getSections(line):
  strings = re.split(',\\s*', line)
  
  sections = []
  section = []
  for x in strings:
      if x == 'juice':
          section.append(x)
          sections.append(section[:])
          section = []
      else:
          section.append(x)
  if len(section) > 0:
      sections.append(section)
      del section
  
  return sections

for s in map(getSections, lines):
  print(s)
```

```
[['applejuice', 'orangejuice', 'juice'], ['applejuice', 'pineapple juice', 'juice'], ['berriesjuice']]
[['carrotjuice', 'juice'], ['pinapple juice', 'water', 'berriesjuice', 'juice']]
```

From a list of lists, you can make a DataFrame, if you wanted.

Comment: My original data is within a dataframe.

Comment: Okay. You can still apply the function shown over each string row and have it return a Series

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Can you explain this step:   if len(section) > 0:
      sections.append(section)
      del section

Comment: For example, at `berriesjuice` in the first list, you still need to append that `section`. `del` is just for variable cleanup. It's not necessary